# How to Enable Permissions on Discussions (Comments) in Custom Portlet in Liferay

Tags: permissions, liferay-6, portlet

I realize this question has been asked before but there doesn't seem to be a complete answer so I'll ask with specifics and what has been tried. It has also been asked many times in other forums with either no answers or very incomplete with few details.

I have been able to add Comments (Discussions) to my custom portlet using the 'liferay-ui:discussion' taglib in Liferay 6.1.20 After searching around I have finally got it to work using the following setup:

#### JSP Page

```
<portlet:actionURL 
            var="discussionURL"
            name="addDiscussion"/>

        <liferay-ui:discussion
            className="<%= Announcement.class.getName() %>"
            classPK="<%= announcement.getPrimaryKey() %>"
            formAction="<%= discussionURL %>"
            formName="fm2"
            ratingsEnabled="<%= false %>"
            redirect="<%= currentURL %>"
            subject="<%= announcement.getHeadline() %>"
            userId="<%= themeDisplay.getUserId() %>"
        />
```

#### Portlet Class

Note: Class extends MVCPortlet

```
public void addDiscussion(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse){  
    try {           
        //invokeTaglibDiscussion(actionRequest, actionResponse);
        PortletActionInvoker.processAction("com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.action.EditDiscussionAction", null, actionRequest, actionResponse);
    } catch (Exception e) {  
        _log.error("There was an Error adding a comment to the Announcement");
    }  
}
```

Since class extends MVCPortlet I tried using the *invokeTagLibDiscussion* but no change in permission results. This came from the book *Liferay In Action* (which is a great source of information). So I tried using the *PortletActionInvoker.processAction* method as mentioned in a number of articles.

#### Question

So, now that I have a working Discussion added to my custom portlet, it turns out that *anyone* can edit any other individual's previous comments. Obviously I can't launch a portlet with that security issue. Again researching further, I found the following 'answers'...

- Add Permissions to the resource-actions file [Add Permissions](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/27952445). This seemed the most promising since it made total sense that the Liferay code would utilize the permission system in this manner. What I find interesting is why no tutorials/boods on this topic mention using the *DELETE_DISCUSSION* and *UPDATE_DISCUSSION* permissions. (ie. [Liferay Wiki Article](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+Frameworks#section-Liferay+Frameworks-Comments)) Either way, this didn't resolve my issue even when the owner of this question indicates it did for them.
- Another posted 'answer' indicated to 'just add the permission to the specific role' in the control panel. Not only did they not provide any details as how to accomplish this, but it didn't make any sense since those permission actions wouldn't be in the portlet.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated as this is the final component to my custom portlet project that is hindering me getting it released to my user group.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have same problem with permissions, have you solved ?

Comment: did any of use get the solution? I am using DXP SP4.